# How to show file size and type in UIActivityViewController modal

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

To allow the user to download a file, I use the [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller) provided by Apple. The following code produces the first screenshot:

```
let url: URL = // some url
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url, "A filename"], applicationActivities: nil)
present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: What the code above generates]

However, it does not show the file type (pdf document) and size, as is shown in the screenshot below. All functions of the activity view work (downloading, mailing, etc).

Does anyone know how this information can be displayed using a `UIActivityViewController`?

[image: What Safari shows if you download a PDF Document]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement functionality according to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850483/ios13-share-sheet-how-to-set-preview-thumbnail-when-sharing-uiimage/59014863#59014863) or try to implement `activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_:)` for your sharing file