# Custom header for UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I created UIActivityViewController and everything is ok with it functionality, but I have a question about custom header. How I can  change the header (title, subtitle) of UIActivityViewController and add custom image to the icon on left side of activityView. I attached and image as example

[image]

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/q/57850483/3564632 ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself. I should use `LPLinkMetadata` with `UIActivityViewController`. Full tutorial you can find by this link [Composing Rich Link Previews Using LinkPresentation in Swift](https://richkolasa.netlify.com/posts/2019/07/composing-rich-link-previews-using-linkpresentation-in-swift/).

And yes, this will work only on iOS 13 and above