# UIImage(named: ) works but Bundle.main.url(forResource: , withExtension) doesn't work

Tags: swift, uiimage, bundle

I am trying to get the url of an image in my assets folder to use it as the preview for a UIActivityViewController as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850483/ios13-share-sheet-how-to-set-preview-thumbnail-when-sharing-uiimage). However I am getting nil for the path, even though the UIImage is working. I have checked if the extension is lowercase as suggested in another question and it is indeed. I have also tried using .path

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "emoji-2", withExtension: "jpg") // this is nil
UIImage(named: "emoji-2") // this is not nil
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

To confirm, the asset exists in my Assets library
[image]

Comment: Adding an image to the asset is not the same as adding it to the bundle

Comment: Hey @LeoDabus can you explain me what that means? Is it just not possible to get the URL for an image in Assets or did I not add it correctly?

Comment: No there is no URL. If you need an URL you can add it to your project or get the representation data from your image located in your asset, save it to a temporary location and share its URL

Comment: Understood, thank you.

Comment: @LeoDabus can I ask one more question? If I add the file to a Media folder, I can get the path correctly, and it seems I can use it as UIImage(named: ) also, but only if it's a .png not if it's a .jpg Is that right or did I get something else wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try adding the path extension to the name? `UIImage(named: "emoji-2.jpg")`?

Comment: Adding .jpg worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want to add this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an image to the asset is not the same as adding it to the bundle. If you need an URL you can add it to your project or get the representation data from your image located in your asset, save it to a temporary location and share its URL.